# I don't understand the proof for reducing Subset-Sum to Scheduling with release time.

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, np-complete

I found this proof for showing that Scheduling with Release Time is NP-Hard by reduction to Subset-sum, but I don't understand it:

Scheduling With Release Time:
Given a set of $n$ jobs with processing time $t_i$, release time $r_i$, and eadline $d_i$, is it possible to schedule all jobs on a single machine such that job $i$ is processed with a contiguous slot of $t_i$ time units in the interval [$r_i$, $d_i$]?

Claim: SUBSET-SUM $\leq_p$ SCHEDULE-RELEASE-TIMES.
Prof: Given an instance of SUBSET-SUM $w_1, ... , w_n$, and target $W$,
Create $n$ jobs with processing time $t_i = w_i$, release time $r_i = 0$, and no deadline ($d_i = 1 + \sum_j w_j$)

Create job 0 with $t_0$ = 1, release time $r_0 = W$, and deadline $d_0 = W + 1$

My understanding: so there is some subset of $t_i$ such that their sum adds up to exact $W$, which is the release time of one special job called job 0 and the rest of the jobs have no release / deadline restrictions. I guess the rest of the jobs that are not part of this set will be scheduled after job 0. But I don't understand how this can ensure they don't overlap and how that notation makes the jobs have no deadline. I dont understand how this proof works in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the jobs do not have "no deadline", in fact the choice of deadline is crucial. You have $n+1$ jobs which take total time $1+\sum_j w_j$. Since all of their deadlines are at most $1+\sum_j w_j$, the only way all of them can be successfully scheduled on one machine is if they can be performed back-to-back with no gaps in them. But job $0$ must be performed from time $W$ to $W+1$, so they can only be performed back-to-back with no gaps if some subset of the jobs takes exactly $W$ time, i.e. if the instance of SUBSET-SUM is YES. Conversely, if the instance of SUBSET-SUM is YES, then we have some set of jobs we can schedule back-to-back with no gaps from time $0$ to $W$, and if we then schedule the remaining jobs back-to-back after time $W+1$ we meet the deadline.

Comment: So job 0 is to make use of the subset that sums to W and the deadline is to ensure that the rest of jobs not in the summing subset can also be scheduled.

Comment: @zeion Correct.

Comment: @AlexBecker; I'm little confused here; because if a SubsetSum takes an array $[1,1,2]$ and the target = 6. Then, SubsetSum would return False; but this instance according to transformation would give a set of job (0,1,5), (0,1,5), (0,2,5), (6,1,7). The first element is release time, second is process time, third is deadline. Schedule Problem can schedule all of these jobs without overlap or miss deadline. So SubsetSum() return False but Schedule return True.